# PHP Login System problem... Sending errors from page to page

Tags: php, authentication

I have a login form in every page of a website so the user can login from everywhere.   I have a login.php file that I refer to it from the form (using 'action').

I use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to redirect the user to the same page he logged in from when he succesfully log in or when he logs out.

But if there was a problem logging in, how can I send an error to the same page he is trying to log in?? I have tried sending the error using `$_GET`, like this:

```
// process the script only if the form has been submitted
if (array_key_exists('login', $_POST)) {
    // Login code goes here...

    // If there was a problem, destroy the session and prepare error message
    else {
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'?error');
    exit;
}
```

But the problem is that a lot of pages in the website are like this `details.php?mid=0172495`. They already recive information from the `$_GET` method and for security reasons I cant use another `$_GET` method...

So, How can I pass the error???
Thanks...

Comment: Using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is a bad idea, as clients can block the referrer.  Consider using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] instead.

Comment: PHP_SELF would give the address of the login script, he's trying to find out where they came from. Generally the correct solution to that involves sending the address in a $_GET variable to the login script, to avoid referrer-blocking problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to what Chad Birch said...

In your login script where you redirect, check the HTTP_REFERER value for the character '?'.  If it is present, append '&error' to the HTTP_REFERER and redirect to that.  Otherwise append '?error' to the HTTP_REFERER and redirect to that.

Comment: header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], '?') !== FALSE ? '&error' : '?error'));

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using sessions, after you destroy the session why not create a new one with $_SESSION['error'] or something similar set?  Or alternatively simply don't delete the session at all but set the error which you can immediately check in other pages?

Comment: This is a solution, but it is also not very scalable.  

That is, if your script is served from more than one server, sessions will no longer function unless you create your own session handler that uses a database or some other method that works across multiple servers.

Comment: That's definitely correct, $_GET and sessions seem the easiest ways to pass data from one page to another, but maybe a more robust solution is necessary.  Maybe based on the comment the original poster asked he is able to use $_GET after all.

Comment: If you are running across multiple servers, you should share you sessions between them.  Otherwise you are defeating the purpose of the session variable.  (look into memcached session handler)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "for security reasons I cant use another `$_GET` method", but in the case that there's already something in the query string, you just need to append another variable to it, instead of replacing it.

That is, if the address is like `details.php?mid=0172495`, you should be sending them to `details.php?mid=0172495&error`, whereas if it was just `details.php`, you send them to `details.php?error`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing what you need is to include your login.php file in every page that has the login form and just post to that same page. So you won't need any redirection at all.

This maybe is not a good scalable and maintainable solution, but it is simple. It all depends what kind of app you are writing. But you are saying that you are new to php so you can start like this. You can always go fancy later...